Another Borel Cantelli Lemma Problem
Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.
Let $A_1,A_2,..., A \in \mathcal{F}$ be events with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(A_n\cap A)<\infty$ then: $\mathbb{P}(\limsup A_n)\leq1-\mathbb{P}(A)$
Well, I tried  a lot and after two sheets of paper gone I decided to ask for help.
If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(A_n)<\infty$ then the inequality above holds of course but i struggle to get an actual proof done. I think I have to use some De Morgan's laws or something like that but I don't get it.
I appreciate every hint, thanks in advance.

If $B\subset\limsup A_n$ and $B\cap A \not = \emptyset$, what can you deduce for $P(B)$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n\cap A)$?

If you temporarily accept that $\mathrm{limsup}(A_n\cap A)=\mathrm{limsup}(A_n)\cap A$ holds, do you see how to finish the proof ?

@SimonPitte well i had this on my sheets and tried a lot but actually i dont get the point.

@TheAlertGerbil In this case $\mathbb{P}(B)\leq \mathbb{P}(limsupA_n)$ and every $\omega \in \B$ is in infinitely many $A_n$'s and $\mathbb{1}_{limsupA_n\cap A \cap B}$ is one for infinetly many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ ... at least for those $\omega in A\cap B$ but I am stucked here...

@LostInProbabilities Borel Cantelli tells you something about $\mathrm{limsup}(A_n\cap A)$, and by the hint I’ve given you already, it says something about $\mathrm{limsup}(A_n)$. Can you see now ?

@SimonPitte i dont get it, please tell me!

Since you know that the sum of the probabilities is finite, Borel-Cantelli tells you that $$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \cap A\right) \right) = 0$$
Moreover, given that
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \cap A\right) = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A$$
it follows that
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A \right) = 0$$
Notice that you can write the limit superior as
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A  \right) \cup \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A^C  \right)$$
Noting that the two sets are disjoint and using the Borel-Cantelli result we can write
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n \right)= \mathbb{P} \left(\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A  \right) + \mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A^C  \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A^C  \right) $$
But since $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A^C \subseteq A^C$ it follows that
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( A_n \right) \cap A^C  \right) \le \mathbb{P} \left( A^C \right) = 1 - \mathbb{P} \left( A \right)$$
as required.
